# Need of getchar?

Tags: c, input

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<assert.h>
#define MAX_CHARACTERS 1005
#define MAX_PARAGRAPHS 5

char* get_input_text() {
    int paragraph_count;
    scanf("%d", &paragraph_count);

    char p[MAX_PARAGRAPHS][MAX_CHARACTERS], doc[MAX_CHARACTERS];
    memset(doc, 0, sizeof(doc));
    getchar();
    for (int i = 0; i < paragraph_count; i++) {
        scanf("%[^\n]%*c", p[i]);
        strcat(doc, p[i]);
        if (i != paragraph_count - 1)
           strcat(doc, "\n");
    }

    char* returnDoc = (char*)malloc((strlen (doc)+1) * (sizeof(char)));
    strcpy(returnDoc, doc);
    return returnDoc;
}

int main()
{
    char* text = get_input_text();
    printf("%s",text);
    return 0;
}
```

Input

```
2
Learning C is fun.
Learning pointers is more fun.It is good to have pointers.
```

If I remove getchar();. Program doesn't work, Why is that?
Other wise code works fine and prints the the exact input as output.

Comment: Did you try to run it in a debugger and step through? What did you see?

Comment: Also, if you do this `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", p[i]);`, why leave the previous `scanf()` _unattended_?

Comment: Sir I don't know much programming, This was the question's input taking step on HackerRank.

Comment: I am no Sir, and you're expected to do some research on your own before posting here (for your own good). A spoon-fed solution is not going to help you learn.

Comment: `scanf()` is not the best tool for user (or unstructured file) input (I'd even say `scanf()` is a bad tool for user input). Prefer `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you try to give input to this `scanf("%d", &paragraph_count);` you will enter an integer and then press enter key ,`scanf` will take the exact input you said, which means the integer , but leaves `\n` produced by enter key in buffer so if you don't use `getchar();` the next `scanf` (`scanf("%[^\n]%*c", p[i]);`) will take `\n` as the input character. but when you use `getchar()` this function will take that `\n` from buffer and 
next `scanf` will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%[^\n]%*c", p[i]);` Means read a line and then ignore a char ('\n').

In `scanf("%d", &paragraph_count)` you read a int but left a '\n' in buffer.

So you need `getchar()` to ignore a '\n', or you next scanf will meet a '\n' at the begining and read nothing.